# AWS Amplify : Search and result aggregations with @searchable directive

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

This is a Usage Question, there is no issue right now, but I have ambiguity with @searchable directive,
As you may know, AppSync is good for simple filtering, but searching for data using advanced filters becomes not possible, like sum, average, min, max, regex, total search result count queries

question 1: does add @searchable directive will launch an EC2 instance (or OpenSearch instance) automatically and start invoicing even in idle time without invoking any query?

question 2: for simple queries, is it possible to not use opensearch, and how to tell aws amplify to use AppSync instead for data filtering? (without remove @searchable)

question 3: Do you think using a custom business logic with Lambda function for advanced filters is better than OpenSearch for small-budget projects?

Hope I was clear
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I am not 100% on question 1, here's my views on 2 and 3.

**Question 2:** Yes, use queries as you normally would with AppSync.

**Question 3:** [Use indexing for custom queries](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#configure-a-secondary-index).

```
type Customer @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  phoneNumber: String
  accountRepresentativeID: ID! @index
}
```

I've found searchable is quite expensive, although easier. Using indexing on your tables should be better.

Comment: For geo queries, I don't think we can avoid opensearch !!

Comment: I don't undesrtand this point. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question 1:** does add @searchable directive will launch an EC2 instance
> (or OpenSearch instance) automatically and start invoicing even in
> idle time without invoking any query?

By default, Amplify CLI will configure a t2.small instance type.

```
Name: t2.small
vCPUs: 1
On-Demand Price/hr*: $0.023
(2023)
```

"t2.small" is great for getting started and prototyping but not recommended to be used in the production environment.

It's not like Labdas, so the t2.small node will run in 0-24h.

**[Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?nc2=h_ql_pr_ft&all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all):**
"T2 instances are available to use in the AWS Free Tier, which includes 750 hours of Linux and Windows **t2.micro** instances each month for one year for new AWS customers."

(Check actual "AWS pricing" and "Free tier" for more information)